# CSS: anchor will NOT accept height

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-lists

I have been pulling my hair our for over an hour on this and I just can't understand why it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/blog/">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-4 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/">Front Page</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#mainmenu { position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 0; font-size: 77%; }
div#mainmenu div.menu ul,
div#mainmenu div.menu ul li,
div#mainmenu div.menu ul li a
{
    height: 36px;
}
div#mainmenu div.menu ul {  
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    table-layout: fixed;

    position: relative;
}
div#mainmenu div.menu ul li
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#mainmenu div.menu ul li a
{
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change `div#mainmenu div.menu ul li a` to this:

```
div#mainmenu div.menu ul li a
{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

`a` elements are `inline` by default and you cannot set the height / width of inline elements.

Comment: `inline-block` would probably be more appropriate but this is definitely an option.

Answer (score 7):

The default display type for a link is inline, which does not respond to height or width. Instead, tell your links to be inline-blocks, which preserves the flow of the links but makes them respect your request to be a specific size (height).

```
div#mainmenu div.menu ul li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:36px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try line height instead of height:

`line-height:36px`

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/dP4F9/

Comment: Would be glad to see this in a simple example. Like 3 lines.

Comment: That's why there is a JSFiddle link to an example.