# anchor tag height value won't change

Tags: html, css

I tried all of the solutions enumerated here:

[CSS: anchor will NOT accept height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357862/css-anchor-will-not-accept-height)

namely setting the `<a>` tag to `display:block` and `display:inline-block` respectively to no avail.

Anybody have any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/wrtu538f/9/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="search-bar-locations">
   <a href='#' id='center'>
     SEARCH BY PROGRAM
     <i class='fa fa-sort-desc'></i>
   </a> 
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
 .search-bar-locations a{
   overflow:hidden;
   display:inline-block;
 }

.search-bar-locations #center {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #eab63e;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}
```

Here is what it is rendering the `<a>` as 230px X 70px as opposed to 200 x 40

[image]

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do - it looks like the <a> tag is taking the height that you are giving it.

Comment: @TimMcClure i would like the block with background #eab63e to have a width of 200px and a height of 40px but it renders 230px by 70px height

Comment: ok, so you're really trying to adjust the height of the div. @VladBardalez's answer should solve your issue.

Comment: None of these answers are correct, the padding amount is what is causing this. Either the width and height need to take the padding into account, or use the box-sizing property.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your anchor tag outside you `<div class="search-bar-locations">` as such:

```
<a href='#' id='center'>
  <div class="search-bar-locations">
     SEARCH BY PROGRAM
     <i class='fa fa-sort-desc'></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

**Edit:** anchor tags take the size of anything inside them. So if you want to format the height of the link, change the height of the div inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read how the box model works for block elements. Remember that when you add padding, you will be adding the padded amount to the width and height of the box. That is why you are essentially getting 30px difference between what you expect.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

There is a way around this, by using the box-sizing propery.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

In your example, you would use:

```
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could try this solution, this way u can give height to anchor. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/akshaybhende/6hk4n4b1/

```
//CODE

<div class="search-bar-locations">
   <a href='#' id='center'>
     SEARCH BY PROGRAM
     <i class='fa fa-sort-desc'></i>
   </a> 
  </div>

//CSS

.search-bar-locations a{
   display:block;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 15px;
    line-height:40px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eab63e;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
 }
```